# How to find a vector which is normal to $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

> The plane $\pi$ has equation **r** = $3$**i** + $2$**j** + $s$(**i** + **k**) + $t$(**j** - **k**) and the line $\ell$ has equation **r** = $2$**i** + **j** -$3$**k** + $\lambda$ ($2$**i** - **j**).
>
> (a) Find a  vector which is normal to $\pi$.

My working so far:

**r** = $3$**i** + $2$**j** + $s$(**i** + **k**) + $r$(**j** - **k**)

If **n** is a vector perpendicular to the plane,

then **r**$\cdot$**n** =(**a**+$s$**b**+$t$**c**)$\cdot$**n**

= **a**$\cdot$**n**+$s$**b**$\cdot$**n**+$t$**c**$\cdot$**n**

**r**$\cdot$**n** = ($3$**i** + $2$**j**)$\cdot$**n** + $s$(**i** + **k**)$\cdot$**n**+ $t$(**j** - **k**)$\cdot$**n**

Let **n**=$\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end {matrix}\right)$

**b**$\cdot$**n** = **c**$\cdot$**n** = $0$ since **b** and **c** are perpendicular to **n**.

Taking **b**$\cdot$**n** $=0$,

$\left(\begin{matrix}s\\0\\s\\\end {matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end {matrix}\right)=0$

$s$**x**+ $s$**z** $=0$

**x** = -**z**

Taking **c**$\cdot$**n** $=0$,

$\left(\begin {matrix}0\\t\\-t\\\end {matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end {matrix}\right) =0$

$t$**y** - $t$**z** $=0$

**y** = **z**

If what I have been doing is correct, the vector normal to $\pi$ would be (in terms of **z**), **n**= $\left(\begin{matrix} -z\\z\\z\\\end {matrix}\right)$

Is this the right way to solve this question?

What is a better way to solve the question?

The answer given is -**i** + **j** + **k**.

Comment: The equation of line $\ell$ is used in the second part of the question: (b) Show that the acute angle between $\ell$ and $\pi$ is $\sin^{-1}\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{15}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes your answer is correct although an easier way is to use cross-product of the vectors parallel to the plane (the ones in brackets).

So the normal is $$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: So  both $s$ and $t = 1?$